# Can we run the Voice Recognition inside a service?

Tags: android, voice-recognition

I am wondering as to whether can we run Voice recognition from a service or not.

I hope some Android Experts / Google Engineers provides some valuable inputs on this.

Thanks.

Comment: what are your requirements for wanting to run it in a service? Not that it matters, just curious

Comment: I am actually trying to have a constant service running which would listen for voice commands... this save me from invoking Voice Recognition each time I want to do a voice search..

Comment: Hi mahendraliya! I was wondering if you were ever able to figure out how to implement a constant service checking for voice commands? I would really appeciate if you could help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this could be useful [RecognitionService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/RecognitionService.html)

Comment: any idea how to use it or implement it? Any sample code / snippet which shows that I can invoke Voice Recognition from my service running in background?

Comment: Sorry I don't know of any open source projects that use it and the documentation is lacking.  Looks like it uses the basic AIDL interface binding provided by android.  The API demos project that comes with the sdk has an example so there is someplace to start.